# ORA-12560: TNS:protocol adapter error. After drop the DB

Tags: oracle, oracle19c

I started getting error **ORA-12560: TNS:protocol adapter error**. After I deleted the database

"Выполняется" - Started;

"Автоматически" - Automatically

[image]

all required services are active

---

and in order for everything to work, I need to enter each time such commands as:

1. set oracle_sid=ORCL
2. net start oracleserviceORCL

Answer (score 0):

You should install Oracle home (can be downloaded free from oracle website)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).